# ListView for timetable

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml, winrt-xaml

I'm developing an app that presents a timetable, that looks like this:
[image: my timetable]

However, I have several problems with it:

1. When there are too many items (minutes) to display in 1 row it
   should be broken automatically in several rows (e.g. all rows after
   06 should be wrapped)
2. I don't know where the spacing around minute items comes from. It's not
   item`s margin.
3. When scrolling the timetable list with finger, it only gets scrolled if no minute box is touched. Otherwise the minute box moves a bit, not the
   entire timetable list.

The timetable list is bound to an ObservableCollection of TimetableHour instaces:

```
public class TimetableHour
{
    public sbyte Hour { get; set; }
    public IList<TimetableItem> Items { get; set; }

    public string HourString
    {
        get { return Hour.ToString("00") + ":"; }
    }
}
```

and the XAML page:

```
<Style TargetType="ListView" x:Key="TimetableListViewStyle">
    <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Hidden" />
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,0,60,0" />
    <Setter Property="ItemTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBox Text="{Binding HourString}" 
                             Width="60" Height="50"
                             TextAlignment="Center"
                             Background="CornflowerBlue" Foreground="White" BorderThickness="0"
                             FontSize="23"
                             Padding="10">
                    </TextBox>

                    <GridView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" Height="Auto" SelectionMode="None" IsTapEnabled="False" IsHoldingEnabled="False" >
                        <GridView.ItemsPanel>
                            <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                                <WrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal" />
                            </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        </GridView.ItemsPanel>
                        <GridView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackPanel Background="LightSkyBlue" Width="60" Height="50">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Minute}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="17" FontWeight="Medium" Margin="0,2,0,0"></TextBlock>
                                    <TextBlock  HorizontalAlignment="Center">Tip</TextBlock>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridView.ItemTemplate>
                    </GridView>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

<ListView Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="2" ItemsSource="{Binding Timetable}"
                      Style="{StaticResource TimetableListViewStyle}"
                      SelectionMode="None" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I figured them out:

1. To make the minutes items wrap I needed to specify the exact width
       of the GridView that is used to display them. Alternatively I can use a Grid instead of a StackPanel, to allow to use all available space - see [GridView width inherited from parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16438661/gridview-width-inherited-from-parent)
2. To control the spacing around GridView items you need to define the
   ItemContainerStyle as described here:
   [Windows8 ListView and space between items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11594794/windows8-listview-and-space-beetween-items)
3. To achieve this I can set IsSwipeEnabled="False" on the GridView.