# GridView width inherited from parent

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime

I have a `StackPanel` with a fixed width. Inside that `StackPanel` I have a `GridView`, which `Width` should be limited to its parent width (smth like Width="*").

My sample XAML:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="300" Height="300">
        <TextBox Width="50" Margin="0" Height="50" Background="Blue"></TextBox>
        <GridView >
            <GridView.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </GridView.ItemsPanel>
            <GridView.Items>
                <TextBox Width="50" Margin="0" Height="50" Background="Green"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Width="50" Margin="0" Height="50" Background="Green"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Width="50" Margin="0" Height="50" Background="Green"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Width="50" Margin="0" Height="50" Background="Green"></TextBox>
                <TextBox Width="50" Margin="0" Height="50" Background="Green"></TextBox>
            </GridView.Items>
        </GridView>
    </StackPanel>
```

In this example the `GridView` width is wider than the parent, so some of its items are not displayed (not wrapped). When I set `GridView` width to a fixed value items are wrapped, but I can't use fixed value in my project.

Comment: Why are you using TextBox in GridView ? Please see [WINDOWS 8′S GRIDVIEW – NOT MEANT FOR DATA ENTRY!](http://netitude.bc3tech.net/2013/04/12/windows-8s-gridviewnot-meant-for-data-entry/)

Comment: TextBoxes in my example are only used as sample items, in reality I only present data in that GridView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this scenario it's more beneficial to have a `Grid` rather than a `StackPanel`. The code below will achieve the desired effect (the `GridView` will take up any unused space next to the `TextBox`).

```
<Grid Width="300" Height="300">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="50" />
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBox Grid.Column="0" Height="50" Background="Blue"></TextBox>
            <GridView Grid.Column="1">
                <GridView.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <WrapGrid Orientation="Horizontal" FlowDirection="LeftToRight" />
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </GridView.ItemsPanel>
                <GridView.Items>
                    <TextBox Width="50" Margin="0" Height="50" Background="Green"/>
                    <TextBox Width="50" Margin="0" Height="50" Background="Green"/>
                    <TextBox Width="50" Margin="0" Height="50" Background="Green"/>
                    <TextBox Width="50" Margin="0" Height="50" Background="Green"/>
                    <TextBox Width="50" Margin="0" Height="50" Background="Green"/>
                </GridView.Items>
            </GridView>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try horizontalscrollmode enabled and horizontalscrollbarvisibility to true. But data would not be wrapped.